# PHP echo only if string match

Tags: php, json, if-statement, echo, equals

I'm working on something that echos from an external json page.

However I only need it to echo if `($sub = 'word')` but my code simply renames all `$sub`'s to `'word'` instead of omitting the ones that don't = `'word'`

```
<?php
$jsonurl = "http://site/page.json";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$json_output = json_decode($json);

foreach ($json_output as $page) {
    foreach($page->levels as $level) {
        if (isset($level->sub)) {
            $sub = $level->sub;
            $no  = $level->no;
        if ($sub = 'YES!') { /*Here is the problem*/
            echo $sub . '|'. 'http://site/level/' . $no . '<br />';
        }
    }
}}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used assign (=) instead of is equal (==)

It should go like this:

```
if ($sub == 'YES!') {
    echo $sub . '|'. 'http://site/level/' . $no . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah haha, sorry to waste a question on a simple oversight.

Comment: Things like that happen to the best of us. Just have to pay more attention and work on our debugging methods/skills